# Microsoft Team: How to automate triage task

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

Like we have slash commands in slack, which helps us to perform get or post 
similar to do that do we have anything in Microsoft team and if yes are there any documentations.
I have built some slash commands using pythong in slack but i am not finding anything for teams.

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview)?

Comment: _and if yes are there any documentations_ Have you tried looking at any documentation Microsoft offers for Teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, Teams doesn't provide a 100% direct match to "/slash" commands, but there are equivalents, and they pretty much all involve the use of a Bot. In practice, it really just means going from "/" to "@", as you @mention the bot to invoke it, and it can proceed as needed from there.

That said, there are a few places where you might want to surface this. For instance, the "normal" place is in a chat inside a channel. To make this work, you -can- get away without a Bot, but a Bot is the easiest. If you want to do something *outside* a channel, like just invoking the bot directly, there are two options - interact with the bot in a 1-1 style (in which case the bot appears in the "chat" left menu, as if it were another user). In this case, incidentally, you don't "@mention" the bot because it's the only other person in the chat. The other option is the command text block *right* at the top of the screen in Teams. In this case, you can have the bot open UI to send it parameters in a guided form, even.

So, in short, there are *similar* options to "slash" commands in Teams, but for the most part they involve Bots, so you should look into that more. In particular, look at the Teams development docs for [Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots), [Message Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions), and [Task Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules).

I suggest you also have a look at [Create a bot with the Bot Framework SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: @mahesh, was this able to help you?

Comment: Thanks a lot Hilton started to look into this now.. I will keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

You could [Add custom bots to Microsoft Teams with outgoing webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook).  A webhook is essentially a POST request sent to a callback URL.